Need help finding movie title, mid to late 90's, possibly Disney
Need help finding a movie I can't remember the name of. All I remember is that it's from the 90's. I'm fairly certain it's a Disney movie and that it involves kids in a type of haunted manor/castle.
The one vivid scene that sticks out is one where there is a coat of arms type of puzzle above a fireplace with missing pieces in it, and the last piece they find is a red love heart shaped piece which, when they put it in, opens a secret passage way behind the fire place.
I was sure that the song in the film was "Ooh Aah... Just a Little Bit" by Gina G., but upon searching what films that song has been in, it never came up, so I'm guessing that it wasn't the song but it may have been a similar sounding song, reflecting that mid to late 90's sound.

A quick scan of IMDb doesn’t bring up any films with Gina G on the soundtrack, as you say.

I was sure that it was that song but it can't be, I don't suppose it's possible that the song would be uncredited to the movie if it was in it ?

Could be imdb or wherever else you’re looking isn’t accurate. Tbh, I was quite surprised that song hadn’t been used somewhere.

Welcome to the community. Any other plot details? I hope you enjoy this place as much as I have.

Hey, thanks! There may have been a haunted suit of armour in there somewhere not too sure. The movie is certainly mid to late 90's but as I was born in 1990 my memory of the film is quite hazy to say the least
